# Let IntelliJ IDEA 12 monitor file changes

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm testing IntelliJ IDEA 12 community edition with Scala. I want IntelliJ to listen for changes of files compiled externally by sbt (templates, routes ...). In Eclipse is a setting called "Refresh using native hooks or polling" to do this. Does something similar exist in IntelliJ IDEA?

**Addendum**

That IntelliJ doesn't pick up template changes to check template usage in the rest of the code seems to be a general limitation. Even if I force IntelliJ to synchronize the files those errors are not detected. It's the same with IntelliJ Ultimate.

Answer (score 1):

IDEA has two options related to this:

1. Auto-save when you switch away from IDEA ("frame deactivation")
2. Auto-reload when you switch back to IDEA ("frame activation")

You can configure these options independently: Options -> General: "[√] Synchronize file on frame activation" and "[ ] Save files on frame deactivation". (That's how I configure it.)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you have nothing to do. Unlike Eclipse - except if you indeed check the option to *refresh using native hooks or polling* - IntelliJ is permanently in synch with your file system.

Comment: If I change the signature of a template "constructor" and save the template, IDEA doesn't pickup the change of the compiled template. The code that uses the template seems still to be valid although a parameter is missing.